# How to add Filter in WordPress of custom metabox in custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wann add filter link below image
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please refer this link? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo

Comment: to be clear what is your store names  lists any example please ?

Comment: My store name Like.
1) hearten cafe
2) quick track 40
3) quick track 51
And likewise

Comment: @purvik7373 thank you your question link work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'our_drink_filter' );
/**
 * First create the dropdown
 * make sure to change POST_TYPE to the name of your custom post type
 * 
 * @author Ohad Raz
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function our_drink_filter(){
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }

    //only add filter to post type you want
    if ('our_drink' == $type){
        //change this to the list of values you want to show
        //in 'label' => 'value' format
        $filter_post = array();
        $all_movies1 = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'our_restaurant',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'post_title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
            ) );
            foreach ( $all_movies1 as $movie1 ) :
                //echo $movie1->post_title." ".sanitize_title($movie1->post_title)."<br>";
                array_push($filter_post[$movie1->post_title] = sanitize_title($movie1->post_title));

            endforeach; 
        ?>
        <select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Store Name ', 'wose45436'); ?></option>
        <?php
            $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
            foreach ($filter_post as $label => $value) {
                printf
                    (
                        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                        $value,
                        $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
                        $label
                    );
                }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}


add_filter( 'parse_query', 'drink_posts_filter' );
/**
 * if submitted filter by post meta
 * 
 * make sure to change META_KEY to the actual meta key
 * and POST_TYPE to the name of your custom post type
 * @author Ohad Raz
 * @param  (wp_query object) $query
 * 
 * @return Void
 */
function drink_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'our_drink' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you birendra this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is a plugin. To do that you need to alter the code of that plugin. I couldn't begin to tell you without knowing the contents of that plugin, then you will still have an issue with that opton dispearing if an update for that plugin is loaded. So your best bet is to request it from the author of the plugin.

Comment: I am not using any plugins. This is my custom post type where store name is the custom meta field. I manage it to display in admin panel. Now my clients need it as filter.

Comment: The best I have seen on this is here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/12/modifying-admin-post-lists-in-wordpress/